# Classifying the point $x=2$ for $f(x)=\cos(|x-2|)$

Tags: limits, derivatives

What is the point $x=2$ for this function?
$$f(x)=\cos(|x-2|)$$
I calculated
$$\lim_{x \to2^+} \frac{-\sin(|x-2|)|x-2|}{x-2}=0^-$$
$$\lim_{x \to2^-} \frac{-\sin(|x-2|)|x-2|}{x-2}=0^+$$
and it's a corner point.
If I calculate the limit of the incremental ratio
$$\lim_{h \to0^+} \frac{\cos(|h|)}{h}=+\infty$$
$$\lim_{h \to0^-} \frac{\cos(|h|)}{h}=-\infty$$
it's a cusp.
Can it just be a stationary point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that
$\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$ so $\cos(|x|)=\cos(x)$.

Combine this with
$\cos(x-2)$ at $x=2$
being the same as
$\cos(x)$ at $x=0$
should give you your answer.

Comment: So it's just a max?